# javascript window.open inside php code

Tags: javascript, php

I want to print some javascript in a php script to open a link in a new window:

```
<?php
//php script
$link='http://mylink';
print('<script type="text/javascript">');
print('window.open(' . $link . ', "Link","width=600,height=800")');
print('</script>');
?>
```

But this code didnt work. Any idea how to open a new window with php printed script?

Comment: Don't look at PHP and say that the JavaScript doesn't work. Look at the JavaScript source code in the browser and figure out why /that/ doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some quotes. Replace:

```
print('window.open(' . $link . ', "Link","width=600,height=800")');
```

With:

```
print('window.open("' . $link . '", "Link","width=600,height=800")');
                   ^             ^
```

In JavaScript, this line will result in:

```
window.open("http://mylink", "Link","width=600,height=800")
```

You need the double quotes there to open / close the string.

Comment: works could you only please add the $ sign so the answer will be correct

Comment: Yeap, got it, @user3714829 ;)